# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, cryptography

It's weird. I had this method to encrypt a string:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
public static string Encrypt(this string stringToEncrypt, string key) {
    var cspp = new CspParameters { 
        KeyContainerName = key, 
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore 
    };
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp) { 
        PersistKeyInCsp = true 
    };
    var bytes = rsa.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt), true);
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

And this was my client:

```
private const string EncryptionKey = "pezhman";

static Random random = new Random();
public static int CreateSalt() {
    return random.Next(1000, 9999);
}

public void EncryptSomething() {
    var salt = CreateSalt();
    var plainText = salt + "," + DateTime.Now;
    var encryptionSaltKey = EncryptionKey + DateTime.Now.Date;
    // here im calling encryptor:
    var encryptedValue = plainText.Encrypt(encryptionSaltKey);
}
```

I was using this in an *ASP.NET MVC 4* application. It was working perfectly; but suddenly it stopped working. Actually, in local, I have no problem and it works. But, when I publish my code to the server, I get this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already
>   exists.

Do you have any idea what's happening here? I know I can [grant access to the key to `everyone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445029/645167). **What I'm asking is**, *what just happened at the server? What is changed? What kind of changes can cause the problem?*

Comment: Have you already took a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430966/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-object-already-exist/11445029#11445029

Comment: @rodrigogq yes I already mentioned that in my question. I'm wondering what happened at server? What kind of changes can cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry I haven't cliked the link before. Give some background on this: have you just changed your application? Any windows update installed, what IIS? Is your AppPool using any specific user or the default? Has anyone changed that?

Comment: @rodrigogq well, that's the problem. cause i dont know and my hosting company doesn't answer! also, i changed the key, and problem solved. but still, i'm wondering what just happened! anyway, thanks to comments. good luck

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm asking is, what just happened at the server? What is changed? What kind of changes can cause the problem?

One possibility is the recently released Windows secuirty update [MS14-059](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx), although I can't explain the error message you are getting.

Basically, that update completely uninstalls MVC 4.0.0.0 and replaces it with 4.0.0.1 on your server, and it has caused grief for many people with broken builds. Since cryptography might depend on something very specific to the version number of the DLL, you might want to start there. You can prove or disprove this theory by testing your application on a machine without the above security patch installed to see if it starts working again.

Comment: I replaced the key and it get solved. But about server, I think you are right. Before this happening, server was inaccessible about 3 or 4 minutes. It's possible that they have installed the mentioned (or something like that) update. Unfortunately my hosting company is not responsible. Every thing is guess. But thanks to help. +1