# CryptographicException: Object already exists on Azure with Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, dnx

I am hosting an asp.net 5 website on azure and am getting the folloqing error when trying to create an instance of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` which I am using to generate tokens for Basic Authentication. It has worked for me in previous publishes of my web project to the azure server however it started throwing the error after a publish. No code was changed related to this.

`CryptographicException: Object already exists.`

The code I am calling is as follows:

```
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity, new Claim[0], "BearerToken", "", "");
        // Use the KeyContainerParams from our token options, this ensures that we retrieve
        // the same keys both here and in the token validator configured in Startup.
        using (var rsaCsp = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, _tokenOptions.KeyContainerParams))
        {
            // Create signing credentials from the current RSA key provided by the 
            // crypto service provider.
            var signingCreds = new SigningCredentials(
                new RsaSecurityKey(rsaCsp.ExportParameters(true)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

            // Generate the token using these signing credentials.
            var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(
                issuer: _tokenOptions.Issuer,
                audience: _tokenOptions.Audience,
                signingCredentials: signingCreds,
                subject: claimsIdentity,
                expires: expires.DateTime
            );

            // Write the token as a json string.
            var token = handler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            _logger.LogVerbose("Generated token {0} with RSA", token);
            return token;
        }
```

What could possibly be the cause? This code has not changed since initial implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException -object already exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430966/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-object-already-exist)